# jackson-avro set bytes is failing

Tags: jackson-databind

I am using jackson-dataformat-avro and its failing when trying to set bytes in AvroParserImpl.java  (setBytes method and failing in bb.remaining() as byteBuffer is null)
I am using JsonParser from 2.1.1 version of jackson-dataformat-avro
Do I need to set anything specific for avro bytes datatype in jackson ?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Any idea on how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Any reply please ?